# Zoom Meeting URL using the fire fox profile creation is not launched correctly in version of windows 7 PC

Tags: python, zoom-sdk, ride

Zoom Meeting URL using the fire fox profile creation is not launched correctly in version of windows PC is 6.1 NT  ,mozilla firefox version : 85.0.2 if any solution  using the ride ide or python code suggest some help for it